# SwiftUI: How can I make a Spacer in a List unselectable in editMode?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a List view in my SwiftUI app(ios15.0 and above), and I need to add a Spacer at the end of the list to implement scrolling to the end, even if the last text has multiple lines.

However, when the list enters edit mode, the Spacer also gets a checkmark and can be selected with the last item. How can I make the Spacer unselectable?

I've tried adding the .disabled(true) modifier to the Spacer, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there a way to make the Spacer unselectable without affecting the rest of the list?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

enter edit mode:
[image]

select last item or spacer:
[image]

code for minimum implement:

```
struct TestScrollView: View {
    @State private var multiSelection = Set<String>()
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
    @State var messages: [String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            Button {
                editMode = EditMode.active
            } label: {
                Text("edit")
            }

            List(messages, id: \.self, selection: $multiSelection) { message in
                Text(message)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                
                if(message == messages.last) {
                    Spacer()
                        .id("end_text")
                        .disabled(true)
                }
            }.onAppear() {
                scrollView.scrollTo("end_text", anchor: .bottom)
            }.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` initialiser that you are using computes one row from each invocation of the closure, with each message as the parameter.  It does not create two rows just because you put two views in the view builder closure. It can only create exactly `message.count` rows.

So the last row of the list consists of the `Text` *and* the `Spacer`, which is why you will select both by tapping on either the `Text` or the `Spacer`.

The `Spacer` should be its own row. Use an initialiser that allows you to specify all the rows of the list.

```
List(selection: $multiSelection) {
    ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
        Text(message)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .id(message)
    }
    Spacer().id("end_text")
}
.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
.onAppear {
    scrollView.scrollTo("end_text", anchor: .bottom)
}
```